# C# RDLC Report add first row dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, rdlc

I am getting data with this query.

```
SELECT id, name, debit, credit, debit - credit as balance 
FROM transactions
```

and I am getting these results:

```
id    name         debit     credit    balance
-----------------------------------------------
1     umer         100         0         100
2     umer          0         50          50
3     umer          0         10          40
4     umer          200        0         240
```

but I want a previous balance row. I want result like this

```
id    name         debit     credit    balance
----------------------------------------------
               Previous Balance          50
1     umer         100         0         150
2     umer          0         50         100
3     umer          0         10          90
4     umer          200        0         290
```

Can anyone suggest me how I can add that row at top?

Comment: i have to select that row from database also. so a query will be run.

Comment: You could use UNION in your query to add an extra row

Comment: Try using row headers.

Comment: @DTs can u guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Union All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) set operator to join two queries to get your result.

For example,

```
SELECT
   null as id,
   null as name,
   'Previous Balance' as debit,
   null as credit,
   [PrevBalance]
FROM previousBalanceTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
   id,
   name,
   debit,
   credit,
   debit - credit as balance 
FROM transactions
```

Where the first query selects the relevant data for the previous balance.

Comment: can u please check this question. that was the real query. i am getting error in date. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786431/rdlc-report-convert-a-text-into-datetime-in-sql-select-query?noredirect=1#comment36584443_23786431

Comment: @user3631434 not sure where date has come from - there is no mention of this in your code/question.