# RDLC report convert a text into datetime in sql select query

Tags: sql-server, rdlc

I am using this query in dataset to show my data in rdlc report. but it gives error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Query:

```
SELECT
    NULL AS tno, 
    NULL AS accode, 
    NULL AS acname, 
    '2014-05-01' AS date, NULL AS truck, 
    NULL AS weight, 
    NULL AS quality, 
    NULL AS debit, 
    NULL AS credit, 
    SUM(debit) - SUM(credit) AS balance
FROM 
    transactions AS transactions_1
WHERE 
    (accode = @accode) AND (date < @datefrom)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    tno, accode, acname, date, 
    truck, weight, quality, debit, credit, debit - credit AS balance
FROM 
    transactions AS transactions_1
WHERE 
    (accode = @accode) AND (date BETWEEN @datefrom AND @dateto)
```

Can anyone please help me in this case?

table create code here for test purpse.

```
CREATE TABLE "transactions" (
"id" INT NOT NULL,
"tno" INT NOT NULL,
"pno" INT NOT NULL,
"sno" INT NOT NULL,
"crno" INT NOT NULL,
"cpno" INT NOT NULL,
"accode" INT NOT NULL,
"acname" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
"date" DATE NOT NULL,
"truck" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
"weight" DECIMAL NULL,
"quality" INT NULL,
"debit" MONEY NOT NULL,
"credit" MONEY NOT NULL,
"amount" MONEY NOT NULL,
"comment" TEXT NULL,
"rate" MONEY NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Using this table creation script, the query works just fine (without having any data in the table, of course). So I suspect something in your data stored in that table is causing this error....

Comment: the query is running. but when i right click on dataset(in visual studio 2013) and select "preview data" then it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will cast the date to the date type.

```
CAST('2014-05-01' AS DATE) AS date
```